# Google Home Incorrectly pronouncing the word "resume"

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm developing a new action that sends the word "resume" (as in pause/play/resume) to be spoken. When this happens Google Home will pronounce the word as "résumé".

I know SSML supports the  tag to handle pronunciations but it doesn't look like that is implemented currently with Google Home.

Worst-case I could hack the text to be "re zoom", but I'd rather find a more elegant solution.  Ideas?

Comment: Wow, +1 for "re zoom"!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an ideal solution, but you can use the [<sub> tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/#edef_sub) for SSML to simulate the correct pronunciation.  Try something like:

```
<sub alias="re zoom">resume</sub>
```